# How to structure a lookup based on two keys in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, lodash, lookup-tables

I have more than ten thousand objects that represent some information about two `ids` that looks like:

```
muchData = [
    {
        ids: ["123", "234"],
        interestingData: 1
    },
    {
        ids: ["123", "345"],
        interestingData: 2
    },
    ...
];
```

I am currently using lodash to find the one object that matches the two `ids` like:

```
function findData(id1, id2) {
    return _.filter(muchData, function(d) {
         return d.ids.indexOf(id1) > -1 && d.ids.indexOf(id2) > -1
   })
}
```

where there isn't a guarantee of the order I will receive id1 and id2 (i.e. the first value in the `ids` array could be either id1 or id2).

Is there a better way of representing this problem to avoid having to filter the entire `muchData` array for every lookup?

Comment: How many times do you have to call `findData`? Would it be worth it to restructure your data ?

Comment: Potentially 50+ times on the client. It help populate rows of information as the user is applying different filters. I could fetch the data from the server each time the filters are applied, but all of the other data is already on the client and I was trying to avoid that roundtrip. I am open to restructuring the data, but would ideally keep everything on the client.

Comment: Are any of the `id` property-values (those in the array) guaranteed unique? If so, I'd suggest combining the individual ids together (from `id : ["123", "234"]` to `id : "123234"`) and searching and then searching by that combined property-value *or* creating an array and using the combined key as the index (although this will probably create a very large array with many empty/undefined entries). If, however, there's no guaranteed unique values then you're limited to searching as you already are *or* to having to redesign the back-end to guarantee unique `id` property values...

Comment: ...possibly using a look-up table.

Comment: The `ids` are guaranteed to be unique. I had considered creating a lookup object with keys like `123-234` and then doing two lookups to account for the random order (i.e. looking for `123-234` and `234-123`), but wanted to see if there were other approaches before doing down that path :)

Comment: @DavidThomas has the right idea. Make it an object instead of an array so you can access it by key value. So you could have something like `muchData = {'123234':{'ids':['123', '234'], 'interestingData':1}, '123345':{...}, ....}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a hash table. With sorted ids for unique keys.

```js
var muchData = [{ ids: ["123", "234"], interestingData: 1 }, { ids: ["123", "345"], interestingData: 2 }, ],
    hash = muchData.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        var k = a.ids[0] < a.ids[1] ? a.ids[0] + '|' + a.ids[1] : a.ids[1] + '|' + a.ids[0];
        r[k] = r[k] || [];
        r[k].push(a);
        return r;
    }, {});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(hash, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Originally a (verbose) comment, expanded slightly into an answer.

Given the nature of the array:

```
muchData = [
    {
        ids: ["123", "234"],
        interestingData: 1
    },
    {
        ids: ["123", "345"],
        interestingData: 2
    },
    ...
];
```

If, as you say in [your comment to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114957/how-to-structure-a-lookup-based-on-two-keys-in-javascript#comment57950713_35114957):

> The ids are guaranteed to be unique.

Then the easiest approach would be to use the combined `id` property-values as an index for the array:

```
var sortedData = [],
    muchData.forEach(function (obj, index, array) {
        sortedData[ parseInt( obj.id.join(''), 10) ] = obj.interestingData; 
    });
```

And then using that created array to search for the `interestingData` you wish to retrieve. The bonus of this is that it only has to happen once (per client-visit), but this could also, of course, be done on the server side (once-only) to make it easier.

Or, rather than an array, you could convert the array to an Object and use the combined `id` properties as keys (which may be more sensible than creating an array with, probably, lots of empty/undefined entries):

```
muchData = [
    {
        ids: ["123", "234"],
        interestingData: 1
    },
    {
        ids: ["123", "345"],
        interestingData: 2
    },
    ...
],
objOfData = {},
muchData.forEach(function (obj, index, array) {
    objOfData[ obj.id.join('') ] = obj;
});
```